# Magento 1.9 Sales Order grand total showing value 0

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, zero-subtotal

Magento 1.9 Sales Order grand total showing value 0

[image]

[image]

Does my table affect?

Comment: @Sumit Actually i canceled before, showing values. https://snipboard.io/ikh1Xx.jpg

Comment: Check the totals in the database table sales_flat_order for this order and check what values are present there for this order

Comment: @Sumit Grand total field value 0.

Comment: @Sumit Does my table affected?

Comment: No Zus, the table is not affected. Check is there is any condition in the code for the order total is less than 1, or try to place an order with $1 and cancel the order and then check what happens.

Comment: @Sumit FYI https://snipboard.io/EgOwU4.jpg

Comment: The order total will be displaying 0 everywhere if the order total value is 0 in the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101771/discussion-between-zus-and-sumit).